# Extract nested fields from JSON using Select-Object

Tags: json, powershell

I have a JSON file which I converted using `ConvertFrom-Json` and I want selected fields from it. I tried to pipeline the output to `Select-Object` but I was able to get the name and not other details.

Below is my output of `ConvertFrom-Json` and my script.

```
display_name   : TEL05
name           : TEL05
is_muted       : False
meta           : @{agent_checks=System.Object[]; timezones=System.Object[]; winV=System.Object[]; machine=AMD64; platform=win32; 
                 gohai={"cpu":{"cpu_cores":"12","cpu_logical_processors":"24","family":"6","mhz":"2497","model":"63","model_name":"Intel(R) 
                 Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50GHz","stepping":"2","vendor_id":"GenuineIntel"},"filesystem":[{"kb_size":"358396","mounted_on":
                 "","name":"\\\\?\\Volume{00241358-f193-11e7-80b3-806e6f6e6963}\\"},{"kb_size":"104499196","mounted_on":"C:\\","name":"\\\\?\
                 \Volume{00241359-f193-11e7-80b3-806e6f6e6963}\\"},{"kb_size":"Unknown","mounted_on":"D:\\","name":"\\\\?\\Volume{0024135d-f1
                 93-11e7-80b3-806e6f6e6963}\\"}],"gohai":{"build_date":"Mon Jun  5 18:30:34 GMT 
                 2017","git_branch":"last-stable","git_hash":"7de20ed","go_version":"go version go1.6.4 windows/amd64"},"memory":{"total":"34
                 261516288"},"network":{"ipaddress":"10.13.52.15","ipaddressv6":"fe80::dcf6:212:7ce0:8feb%16","macaddress":"44-A8-42-3A-9D-E9
                 "},"platform":{"GOOARCH":"amd64","GOOS":"windows","goV":"1.6.4","hostname":"TELXCVOIP04","kernel_name":"Windows","kernel_rel
                 ease":"6.3.9600","machine":"x86_64","os":"Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard","pythonV":"2.7.12"}}; host_id=363974563; 
                 pythonV=2.7.12; processor=Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel; agent_version=5.14.0}
host_name      : TEL05
has_metrics    : True
```

I want host name and agent_version (inside meta tag). how do I achieve this?

I tried the below but it did not work.

```
$jsonstring = (Get-Content 'servers.JSON') | ConvertFrom-Json
$jsonstring.rows| select name, meta.agent_version
```

Comment: You shouldn't call an object that comes out of `ConvertFrom-Json` "jsonstring", that's misleading. It's neither a string, nor is it JSON, for that matter. The JSON string is what `Get-Content` returns. After conversion it's an object, you should call it a sensible name - " servers" would work fine. Also, please always use the `-Encoding` parameter for `Get-Content`, because there is no magic file encoding detection and `Get-Content` will easily get it wrong. For most JSON files, specifying UTF-8 encoding is appropriate. The same applies to `Set-Content`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use "dot notation" to index into nested hashes with `Select-Object` - only actual keys are supported, and `meta.agent_version` does not exist as its own key.

`Select-Object` can calculate new values for you, though, and traversing a nested object is a calculation. For this you can use the `@{ name="new propery name"; expression={ script block } }` notation, which can be abbreviated to  `@{ n="propery name"; e={ script block } }`.

You can freely mix this form with actually existing properties, so this would work:

```
$jsonstring.rows | select name, @{n="AgentVersion"; e={ $_.meta.agent_version } }
```

The `$_` refers to the context object, just like in the `Foreach_Object` cmdlet.

Be aware that "dot notation" like `$_.meta.agent_version` will generally select *all* values matching this path, which means it can return an array if more than one value matches. Not an issue in this particular case, but easily overlooked when using dot notation on nested objects.

Comment: For anyone reading this today: in the latest version of powershell, the colons must be replaced by equal signs (as in `select @{n="Label"; e= {...}}`).

Comment: @N.I. Good catch, thanks! The `=` has always worked, I've changed my answer accordingly.